# Plot to visualize a) Cluster size over years b) movement between clusters

Tags: r, plot, graphics

As the result of kmean clustering I assigned persons to different clusters over several years.
See the code for a small example.

```
 df <- data.frame(
personID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
cluster2008 = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
cluster2009 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,3),
cluster2010 = c(1,1,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)
```

I want to present the following aspects in a plot:

- Changes in Cluster sizes over the years
- From which Clusters to which clusters individual change

So for example if the Clusters develop like this

**2008**: C1=100, C2=100, C3=100, C4=100
**2009**: C1=95, C2=95, C3=102, C4=108

I want to visualize where the 5 persons from C1 moved to etc.
Are they now in C2/C3/C4?

I try to get a plot that looks somewhat like the Chart in the image attached.
It shows how many voters of a certain party changed their preference towards another party in a later election.

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAMPE.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a go at it with the `tidyverse` and `ggalluvial` packages

```
library( tidyverse )
library( ggalluvial )

#prepare data for plotting
plotdata <- df %>%
  #melt data to long
  pivot_longer( cols          = starts_with("cluster") ,
                names_to      = "year",
                names_pattern = "^cluster(.*)",
                values_to     = "cluster" ) %>%
  #alter plot columns
  mutate( cluster = as.factor( cluster ), #clusters are discrete
          weight = 1 )#each person counts as 1 

ggplot(plotdata,
       aes(x = year, stratum = cluster, alluvium = personID, y = weight,
           fill = cluster, label = cluster)) +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum( alpha = .5 ) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 3) +
  #theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("movement over clusters")
```

[image]